# Numerical continuation VS Solving ODEs

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

Consider a system of $n-1$ (independent) equations in $n$ unknowns. Generically, the solutions are families of curves. When an point of one curve is known, it is possible to do [numerical continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_continuation) to get all the curve (numerically of course).

The advantage of numerical continuation techniques is not clear for me, given that the system can also be written as a system of ODEs for which many efficient techniques exist.

For example, consider the trivial case:
$$ f(X)=x_1+\sin(x_2^2)$$
with $X^\top =  [x_1\ x_2]$. The solutions of $f(X)=0$ are the solutions of

$$\nabla_X f(X(t))\cdot X'(t) = 0   \qquad {\textit{i.e.}}\qquad x_1'(t)+2x_2(t)x_2'(t)\cos(x_2(t)^2)=0$$
where $t$ is the curvilinear coordinate of the considered curve. This equation can be complemented by $x_1'(t)^2+x_2'(t)^2=1$, yielding two ODEs in two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. As for continuation, solving it numerically requires initial conditions, for instance $x_1(0)=0$ and $x_2(0)=0$.

So my question is, what is the point of pseudo arc-length continuation and other numerical techniques compared to writing the problem as ODEs?

Comment: The advantage of these predictor-corrector type methods is that they check that you are close to the true curve at all times (or at least that $f(X)$ is small at all times). ODE methods tend to have gradually growing error and so they may lack this property.

Comment: On the other hand, there *are* numerical methods for ODEs with a conserved quantity. Look up symplectic numerical methods. These can be used to solve problems like those you are describing in a robust manner.

Comment: @Ian I think that's exactly the point indeed. Regarding symplectic numerical methods, the quantity to conserve would be $f(X)=0$ I guess?

Comment: Correct. Then you just choose a speed at each point however you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predictor-corrector methods like pseudo-arclength continuation guarantee that $f(X)$ stays small at each point along the curve, through the corrector step. They can't *necessarily* ensure that $X$ is very close to the curve itself, if the curve does something weird, but bifurcation theory (and numerical bifurcation detection) can be used to avoid such issues. This property gives robustness to this class of methods.

By contrast, standard numerical methods for ODE (e.g. the Dormand-Price method, built into Matlab as ode45) tend to have gradually accumulating errors, which causes them to lack robustness in this sense.

By contrast to *that*, there are numerical methods for ODE which have conserved quantities. Such methods have a numerically conserved quantity which is either the same as the true conserved quantity or some numerical perturbation of it. Some of these (used for Hamiltonian systems) are called symplectic methods. In general such methods have robustness in the same way as the predictor-corrector methods.

A good test problem for this sort of thing is just the familiar $x^2+y^2=1$. Standard ODE methods applied to your system with this $f$ will tend to drift away from the circle.

Comment: Using Mathematica, `NDSolve[{2 x[t] x'[t] + 2 y[t] y'[t], x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]` works "perfectly".

Comment: @anderstood NDSolve is likely to be much more clever than something like ode45, and *massively* more clever than Euler's method.

Comment: Adding `WorkingPrecision -> 4` to the previous command shows the drift :)

Comment: @anderstood That...is actually not the sort of drift that I was speaking of. The drift that I'm describing should still be present even in exact arithmetic, simply because you move from one circle to a *different* circle at each step. This is easiest to see with Euler's method, where you can geometrically see that the distance from the origin grows by $O(h^2)$ with each step. Floating point issues matter of course, but they are not really what I was talking about.

Comment: What about this one (assuming you have Mathematica): `NDSolve[{grad.{x'[t], y'[t]} == 0, x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 50}, StartingStepSize -> .2, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}]`? The output is plotted [here](http://imgur.com/a/rJpM5).

Comment: I don't actually have mathematica to try, but yeah I would expect that to perform very badly.

Answer (score 4):

A standard example of numerical continuation is tracking unstable periodic orbits in dissipative dynamical systems: You have a periodic orbit that is a solution of your differential equations, which is not an attractor but a repellor, i.e., solutions that are close to but not on your orbit will drift away from it.

Assume that you have initial conditions that are exactly located on such an orbit (which often already is impossible). If you integrate this system with an ODE solver, the inevitable numerical errors will cause your trajectory to slightly stray from your orbit. Since your orbit is repelling, this distance will inevitably blow up.

Continuation methods avoid this problem. (Also note that symplectic integrators are not applicable here, since the systems aren’t Hamiltonian.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited my answer.